# RMarkdown code syntax inside a block quote

Tags: r-markdown

Is there a way to have code syntax inside a block quote using RMarkdown (knitr, Knit to HTML)?
Example Rmd file:

````
---
title: "MyTitle"
author: "Me"
date: "Today"
output:
  html_document:
    fig_caption: true
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
--- 

# Introduction

> My block quote
saying things here
```
some code here, but within the block quote
and more of the same here
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out a simple two-space indent will do it:

````
> My block quote
saying things here
  ```
  some code here, but within the block quote
  and more of the same here
  ```
````

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here are two options for putting a code chunk inside a block quote. I prefer the second because I can still run the chunk as see its output in RStudio (and it's easier to copy from).

````
> Example 1:
> 
> ```{r}
> 10 * 2
> ```

<blockquote>
Example 2:

```{r}
10 * 2
```
</blockquote>
````

[image]